# Why aren't my styles in my Polymer custom element being recognized?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

For some reason the internal (:host) styles for the Polymer custom element aren't loading. I'm using the actual fancy_button component from pub (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fancy_button).

hello_world.html

```dart
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/fancy_button/fancy_button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../lib/components/first-component/first-component.html">
</head>

<body>
<button is="fancy-button">Wooot!</button>
<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
```

fancy_button.html:

```dart
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<polymer-element name="fancy-button" extends="button">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff5db1 0%,#ef017c 100%);
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 2em;
        border: 0;
        font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
        padding: 30px;
      }

      :host(:hover) {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      :host(:active) {
        font-size: 3em;
      }
    </style>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="fancy_button.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Looks fine. Do the Dartium developer tools show some error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to the Dartium from the Dev Channel (http://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/latest/dartium/dartium-macos-ia32-release.zip) and it worked. So styles in Polymer web components don't seem to work in earlier versions of Dartium – either get the Dev Channel version as Günter had suggested or `pub build` and see it working in regular Chrome instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works for me (I get a big pink 'Woot' button, which increases it's size when clicked)

when I comment out this line

```
<!--<link rel="import" href="../lib/components/first-component/first-component.html">-->
```

I also had to add

```
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/hello_world.html
```

to pubspec.yaml (for dev channel Dart version 1.5.0-edge)

This might be the reason why it work here but not for you
but I can't see anything in CSS that wasn't already supported in Dart 1.4.

I also kept the polymer dependency (0.10.1+1)

Comment: Hi Günter. I removed that line, still no go. Here's my code: https://github.com/DaveNotik/woven_sandbox

Comment: Are you seeing the styles applied? Yes, I have Dart 1.4.3. I've added the transformers. I just realized that it does work after `pub build` in /build (in Chrome) but not in regular /web (in Dartium). Any reason for that? Does it actually have to be built for it to work?

Comment: Yes, I get a big pink 'Woot' button.

Comment: Then it's the CSS selector that your Dartium version doesn't yet support. I have Dartium 36 and yours is probably 34. Seems I lost track when these changes actually took place. It's a while that I switched to Dart 1.5.0-edge.